# Method for determining probe angle by analyzing skewed sine wave

Tags: fft, dtft

I've got a fun problem and would be curious to get feedback on how some of you would go about solving this.

Imagine I have a probe and am scanning the surface of some material. This material surface is described by a perfect cosine signal. If my probe is perfectly normal to the surface, my probe will output a "1 to 1" match of the surface signal (excluding some DC offset).

However, if my probe is not perfectly normal to the surface, the collected signal would appear to be a skewed sinusoid. I've put together a simple diagram of set up.

[image]

Currently, my method for determining the probe angle would be to determine the frequency content of the signal. In the case of the probe being perfectly normal to the surface, I would expect that frequency domain would show a single impulse corresponding to the surface frequency.

In the case of the angled probe, I would expect to a find a range of frequencies. Obviously the peak would still correspond to the dominant spatial frequency, however, there would now be a certain bandwidth associated the frequency domain. This bandwidth is associated with the fact that the collect signal is a skew sinusoid.

My question would then be, how would I correlate signal bandwidth to probe angle?It would be nice to get an analytical solution to signal bandwidth and probe angle.

Furthermore, if anyone else could see a way of determining probe angle that isn't frequency domain related, I would be interested in hearing it.

Edit: As I think about this problem more, I'm becoming less confident in whether or not probe angle would create a skewed sinusoid. Assuming the angle doesn't exceed the max slope found in the signal, I'm starting to think the resulting signal would simply be a phased offset sinusoid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume:

- The probe is like a line, infinitely narrow.
- We move the probe along the $x$ dimension, parallel to the large-scale surface, and from each position, *probe* the surface:
- The probe is extended to the direction it is pointing to until it meets the surface. (An alternative assumption would be that probing is done to the direction $y$, that of the normal of the large-scale surface, **in which case the waveform measured would be sinusoidal** unless the probe stem meets the surface before the tip. I wonder if your edit describes this scenario.)

Equation of line starting at coordinates $(x_0, 0)$ and with a positive slope $k = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \ge 1$ (where $1$ is the maximum slope of the sinusoid of Eq. 2, to ensure continuity):

$$y = k (x - x_0)\tag1\\
\Rightarrow x = x_0 + \frac yk.$$

Equation of the first period of the constant-biased sinusoid, spanning $0 \le x \le 2\pi$:

$$y = 1 - \cos(x)\tag2\\
\Rightarrow x = \begin{cases}
\arccos(1 - y)&\text{if }0 \le x \le \pi\\
2\pi - \arccos(1 - y)&\text{if }\pi \le x \le 2\pi.
\end{cases}$$

By Eq. 2 the period starts at $(0, 0)$ and ends at $(2\pi, 0)$, which makes the corresponding period of the skewed sinusoid also start and end at these points. We obtain the waveform by solving $y$ as function of $x_0$ from the system of Eqs. 1 and 2. Unfortunately there is no closed form solution, but we can still make some plots:

[image]
*Figure 1. The skewed waveform for different values of the constant $k$. At $k=\infty$, the waveform is equal to the constant-biased sinusoid. The waveform shown represents the probe tip $y$ position as function of the coordinate $x_0$ at which the probe shaft crosses the $y$ axis. If you desire the "probe length" waveform, you need to multiply this waveform by a factor $\tfrac{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}{k}$.*

I doubt that you will be able to find an analytical solution in frequency domain. What we can do is determine $k$ based on the waveform peak location $x_0 = x_p$ by setting $y = 2$, for which the system of Eqs. 1 and 2 gives:

$$k = \frac{2}{\pi - x_p}.\tag{3}$$

To get the angle $\phi$ by which the probe angle deviates (moderately) from the normal of the large-scale surface:

$$\phi = \operatorname{atan2}\left(1, k\right) = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\pi - x_p, 2\right).\tag{4}$$

Comment: This is a very good derivation. I'm curious though how difficult the problem becomes when the sensor contains noise. I would assume it's difficult to determine the correspond peak location in that case.

Comment: Then I think it is better to compare the full experimental waveform against numerically solved theoretical waveforms for different $k$.